# Can I use Forwardable to delegate a constant in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, delegates, constants

Given a class like:

```
class Thing
  CONSTANT = 10
  # other code
end
```

And another like:

```
class Other
  def initialize
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  def method
    puts CONSTANT
  end
end
```

Is it possible to extend `Forwardable` to have `Other`'s `CONSTANT` delegate to `Thing`'s constant?

I have tried extending`SingleForwardable` (see docs [here](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/SingleForwardable.html) ) like so:

```
class Other
  extend SingleForwardable

  def initialize
    @thing = Thing.new
  end

  def method
    puts CONSTANT
  end

  def_single_delegator :@thing, :CONSTANT
end
```

and:

```
def_single_delegator :@thing, :constant
```

but neither worked, am I getting the syntax wrong? If not, is there another way?

Comment: You can't delegate constant lookup to something that is not a class or a module. If you want to do that, you could use `const_missing` and `const_get`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is answered by [the documentation (**bold** emphasis mine)](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/forwardable/rdoc/SingleForwardable.html#method-i-def_single_delegator):

> ## `def_single_delegator(accessor, method, new_name=method)`
>
> Defines a **method** *method* which delegates to *accessor* (i.e. it **calls the method of the same name** in *accessor*). If *new_name* is provided, it is used as the name for the delegate method.

So, no, you can only delegate message sends, not constant lookup.

Comment: I always considered constants to be some kind of syntactic sugar for class methods though. I guess that was wrong

Comment: No, a constant is a kind of variable, like global variables, local variables, instance variables, and class variables. It has absolutely nothing to do with methods. (Oh, and there are no class methods in Ruby. There are only instance methods. We may use the word "class method" to talk about an instance method that is defined on the singleton class of an instance of the `Class` class, but that is only a conversational convenience. There are no class methods in the Ruby language.)

Answer (score 1):

Forwardable (and SingleForwardable) let you add class functions to your current class via a module. When you write a delegator you're specifying which methods are being passed on to the receiving object from the original module.

In your example, `def_single_delegator :@thing, :CONSTANT` is being interpreted as the following: Defines a method `:CONSTANT` which delegates to accessor `:@thing` (i.e. it calls the method of the same name in accessor).

As you can see, this is not passing on the value of the constant, instead it's passing on a method with the same name as the constant. If you want to pass on the same value as the constant you can provide an accessor method that returns to you the value of the original constant so that you can assign it in this class.

Comment: Ah I see, so I would have to wrap the constant in a method. I don't get why it doesn't pick up the name though? A constant is _almost_ a class method right? (see here https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide/issues/328 )

Comment: You could also just address the constant in the other class directly, provided it has access to it - something like `Thing::CONSTANT`. As for your other question - A constant is just a type of variable - that github issue is referring to stylistic choices when declaring values inside of a class - in the first case the user is declaring a constant, and in the second case he's providing a accessor method for the constant.